# SharePoint 2013 displaying duplicate accounts in Grant Permission

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I am facing a problem with my SharePoint 2013 farm. When I try to assign a permission for a user, the Grant Permission screen and also all other people picker fields in the portal, are giving me duplicate users for each user in the active directory.

For instance, if I am to assign permission to user Waqas Ahmed, the grant permission screen is returning follow 2 user accounts

1. Waqas Ahmed (DOMAIN\wahmed)
2. Waqas Ahmed (i:0#.w|domain\wahmed)

It works fine if I give permissions to first account, but does not work if I assign permission to second.

Need your help guyz.

Thanks

Waqas Ahmed

Comment: Is this a new farm or upgrded? Are you using claims authentication?

Comment: This is a new farm, and yes the authentication mode is claims.

Comment: Although I do want to mention that I restored a backup of a site collection from our staging environment to this new farm. The staging environment is identical to this farm and running on the same AD.